# How to access suggestion listbox of WPF toolkit autocompletebox in viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, autocompletebox

In my project i am using the autocompletebox of the WPF toolkit from dotnetprojects:

```
<input:AutoCompleteBox Grid.Row="0" 
                       Height="30" 
                       Width="300"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
                       SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       ValueMemberPath="DisplayName"
                       ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AutoCompleteBoxItemTemplate}"
                       ItemFilter="{Binding PersonFilter}"
                       Style="{DynamicResource AutoCompleteBoxStyle}"
                       x:Name="AutoCompleteBox">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TextChanged}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding  ElementName=AutoCompleteBox}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</input:AutoCompleteBox>
```

In the event TextChanged i pass the AutoCompleteBox as parameter to the viewmodel:

```
private void TextChangedInternal(object obj)
{
    var box = obj as AutoCompleteBox;
    ...
}
```

From this point on i have no idea how to access the suggestion listbox within the popup.
My intention is to highlight the entered query within the suggestions.

Has somebody an idea how to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the item template to something you control. This means you set up an AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate. This item template will contain each result found.

[This Tutorial is for silver light](https://jeffwilcox.blog/2008/11/highlighting-autocompletebox/) but is pretty much all you need to create your custom control to highlight the text in the results. Once you have that you add this in the data template of your ItemTemplate.